# What archive file format is good for random access during distributed processing?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, lambda, archive

I'm looking for an archive file type that I can use for processing large archive files in AWS lambda. The entries in the archive are not so large by themselves, the largest maybe 100mb, but there could be a lot of them. My strategy is to create a lambda for processing each entry, where the parameters to my the lambda are a path to the file in s3, as well as a byte range for the entry inside the archive.  This would allow for processing each entry without needing to load the entire file. I can write a format to handle this, but I figure something like this probably already exists.

Not required, but hoping to work with these files in C#.

Comment: Would you please add some part of your code to make your question more clear?

Comment: You don't need to load entire archive in memory. you can use ZipArchive standard .Net class which let you open file from disk and access embedded file using the path of it. you just need to know full path of file inside archive that you want to load.

Comment: I should have been more clear, I'm reading from S3, so using the ZipArchive standard would not work, as I'd need to pull the entire file from S3.  I was hoping to just pull byte ranges from the files.

Comment: You can pull byte ranges from S3 but I'd be surprised if you can find any libraries like ZipArchive that support S3 as a remote file system (directly). Are you able to mount the S3 bucket as a Network Share on the system doing the work (by way of CloudBerry Drive, S3FS or similar)?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your files are not that big, I can suggest the following approach.

1. Function invoked
2. If there is a file in `/tmp` GoTo Step 4.
3. If there is no file in `/tmp` download a new file from S3.
4. **Pop** data from the file in chunks making sure that the remaining file shrinks while you process it.
5. Process the popped chunks of data.
6. If the function is about to timeout, stop processing file and invoke yourself  again (call sibling). It may spawn in the same container or in a different one and will either start processing another file (remaining from some other run) or continue the same one.
7. When file is completely processed - mark it in some way (Tag) in S3.

There are some limitations here:
- You should not care about the order of processing the files and the rows inside files.
- Occasional multiple processing of same chunks of data should not cause any problem.
- You probably want to keep track of processed files also somewhere externally

A pretty similar approach is used in the [`Scheduler` class of the `sosw`](https://docs.sosw.app/en/latest/essentials/scheduler.html) package. This is a Python package not C#, but idea could help you.